# Passing special characters as parameter to Powershell script function

Tags: powershell, azure

I just created a method in powershell script as -

```
function Add-Entity() {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
       $TableName,
       $PartitionKey,
       $RowKey,
       [String]$JsonString
    )


  $entity = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity -ArgumentList $PartitionKey, $RowKey
  $entity.Properties.Add("JsonStringProperty", $JsonString)
  $result = $table.CloudTable.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation]::Insert($entity))
}
```

and I want to pass this complete jSon string as a parameter -

```
Add-Entity -TableName $myTableName -PartitionKey "ABC" -RowKey "XYZ" -JsonString {"TO":["abc@xyz.com","def@xyz.com"],"CC":["pqr@xyz.com"],"BCC":[]}
```

Every time I try to compile, It gives me an error -

> Unexpected token ':["abc@xyz".com"' in expression or statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the JSON uses double quotation marks to delimiter key and values and the same character (double quotation marks) is also used by Powershell for strings "wrapping".

You can use single quotation marks to wrap your hardcoded input json like so:

```
'{"TO":["abc@xyz.com","def@xyz.com"],"CC":["pqr@xyz.com"],"BCC":[]}'
```

So the statement would be:

```
Add-Entity -TableName $myTableName -PartitionKey "ABC" -RowKey "XYZ" -JsonString '{"TO":["abc@xyz.com","def@xyz.com"],"CC":["pqr@xyz.com"],"BCC":[]}'
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!